# How can get inner text of a XElement?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XElement as sample:

```
<trans-unit id="7655230f" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <source>EC<x id="0040" /><g id="0041">　test</g></source>    
</trans-unit>
```

I want get inner text of tag `source` include sub tags:

```
EC<x id="0040" /><g id="0041">　test</g>
```

I had try this code, but it add `xmlns` into sub tag:

```
var oSource = oElement.XPathSelectElement(dNS + ":source", nsManager);
string source = String.Concat(oSource.Nodes());
```

Result:

```
EC<x id="0040" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" /><g id="0041" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">　エレシリンダ</g>
```

How can get inner text of a XElement include sub tags?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be like this

```
var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace ns = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2";
var sourceNode = xml.Element(ns + "source");

foreach (var node in sourceNode.DescendantNodesAndSelf().OfType<XElement>())
{
    // remove namespace
    node.Name = node.Name.LocalName;
}

string source = string.Concat(sourceNode.Nodes());
Console.WriteLine(source);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            string xml = 
                "<trans-unit id=\"7655230f\" xmlns=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2\">" +
                   "<source>EC<x id=\"0040\" /><g id=\"0041\">　test</g></source>    " +
                "</trans-unit>";

            XElement unit = XElement.Parse(xml);
            XNamespace ns = unit.GetDefaultNamespace();

            string ec = (string)unit.Element(ns + "source");
```